# ThinkingSphinx::MissingColumnError: column <name> does not exist

Tags: mysql, thinking-sphinx

I have another TS issue today.

```
rake ts:index
```

returns something like this:

```
Generating configuration to /Users/xxx/config/development.sphinx.conf
rake aborted!
ThinkingSphinx::MissingColumnError: column amplua does not exist
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/type.rb:74:in `type_from_database'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/type.rb:17:in `type'
<and so on...>
```

As long as I get it: Sphinx can't find the column 'amplua' even tho it exists. Here is the "ampluas" table representation from mysql query:

```
mysql> show tables
    -> ;
+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_xxx              |
+----------------------------+
| ampluas                    |
| yyyyyyy                    |
| zzzzzzzzzzzz               |
+----------------------------+
<n> rows in set (0.09 sec)

mysql> describe ampluas;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

amplua_index.rb:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :amplua, :with => :active_record do

    indexes :name, :as => :ampluas

end
```

What's up with it?

Comment: Hi Peter - is this the only index you have? Or are there others? If so, can you share those too?

Comment: Yep, I checked other indicies and found my mistake. >_>